# How to configure deadbolt and play authentication dependencies

Tags: playframework

I am working on play framework authentication module. Some what i can understand the code flow by seeing the play-authenticate-mongo example provided by typesafe activator.

Now, i am trying to develop the sample project using the play authenticate and deadbolt. But, while i am configuring the dependencies i am getting some confusing error.

I have configured the dependencies like following in build.sbt,

```
  name := "PlayAuthenticate"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.feth"      %% "play-authenticate" % "0.6.5-SNAPSHOT",
  javaJdbc,
  javaEbean,
  cache
)

resolvers ++= Seq(
 "play-easymail (release)" at "http://joscha.github.io/play-easymail/repo/releases/",
  "play-easymail (snapshot)" at "http://joscha.github.io/play-easymail/repo/snapshots/",
  "play-authenticate (release)" at "http://joscha.github.io/play-authenticate/repo/releases/",
  "play-authenticate (snapshot)" at "http://joscha.github.io/play-authenticate/repo/snapshots/"
)

play.Project.playJavaSettings
```

Here, i have posted my error,

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: play.core.server.NettyServer.mainDevHttpMode(pl
ay.core.SBTLink, play.core.SBTDocHandler, int)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
        at play.PlayRun$$anonfun$playRunTask$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(PlayRun.sc
ala:232)
        at play.PlayRun$$anonfun$playRunTask$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(PlayRun.sc
ala:91)
        at scala.Function7$$anonfun$tupled$1.apply(Function7.scala:35)
        at scala.Function7$$anonfun$tupled$1.apply(Function7.scala:34)
        at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last compile:run for the full output.
[error] (compile:run) java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: play.core.server.NettySer
ver.mainDevHttpMode(play.core.SBTLink, play.core.SBTDocHandler, int)
[error] Total time: 13 s, completed Dec 23, 2014 7:07:55 PM
```

please help me to resolve this issue and to know about the root cause for this issue.

TIA.,

Comment: this is not an issue about play-authenticate but it seems about netty ..., we need all your configuration but i think you resolve it since it is a long time issue